# Unable to get data from foreign table in mongodb nodejs using $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have just started working on mongodb and I want to get data from foreign table(User) and table(Connection) by performing join but foreign table data is always an empty array

User Schema:

```
[
{key: 1, name: "a"},
{key: 2, name: "b"},
{key: 1, name: "c"},
{key: 2, name: "d"},
]
```

Connection schema:

```
 [
    {initiator_id: 1, target_id: 2}
    {initiator_id: 3, target_id: 4}
 ]
```

And this is my join code

```
const pipeline = [
    {
      $match: {
        initiator_id: { $eq: user_id },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "user",
        localField: "initiator_id",
        foreignField: "key",
        as: "user",
      },
    },
  ];

  mongoose.model("connection").aggregate(pipeline).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

And the console.log response is an array in which the user field is always an empty array

```
[
 {
 connection_id: 'some_id'
 initiator_id: 1
 target_id: 2,
 user: []//this is where I'm expecting data from User table but it is always empty 
 }
]
```

initiator_id, target_id, and key .... all are type Number

Comment: the query looks good, make sure you have used correct collection name in lookup `from: "user",`

Comment: yes, @turivishal the collection name is correct

Comment: see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cg5v64NNMjF), check other possibilities.

Comment: yes the code on playground is working as expected, and the only difference i can see is db.connection.aggregate() and I have used const mongoose = require("mongoose"); mongoose.model("connection").aggregate(); which I believe are same

Comment: Got the issue. I had defined my table like this: const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
But for some reason on mongodb cloud it was stored as "users".... so i changed the code in $lookup to ... from: "users" and it started working
Thanks @turivishal

Comment: oh good, by default it will add `s` after model name if you don't specify collection name.

Comment: Got it... thanks @turivishal